# Deriving quadratic formula using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, quadratics

I have tried to derive the quadratic formula using methods from linear algebra, and I wanted to check if my derivation is indeed valid and correct.

I started of with a pair of simultaneous equations with $2$ unknowns:
$$\begin{align*}
x^2-y &= 0\\
bx + ay+c&=0
\end{align*} $$

What I have done is I have replaced the $x^2$ term with $y$, hence the first equation. Normally I would have put $ay+bx+c=0$ as the first equation, but for the sake of making all the terms align with each other nicely, I have put it as $bx+ay+c=0$.

To solve these simultaneous equations, I have used matrices. When we use matrices, we get the following:
$${\begin{bmatrix}x & -1\\b & a\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}0\\-c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{c}{ax+b}\\-\frac{cx}{ax+b}\end{bmatrix}$$

As mentioned previously, $y=x^2$, which means that $(-\frac{c}{ax+b})^2=-\frac{cx}{ax+b}$. We will solve this equation.

I'll leave out the steps for solving it, since it is just a matter of rearranging to make $x$ the subject and both WolframAlpha and Symbolab believe it to be correct. However, what is interesting is that we get $x = \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, $x = \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$   , which can be expressed succinctly as $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. We have successfully derived the quadratic formula, but what I want to know is if my method is correct and if there is any way in which I could improve my approach.

Comment: "$(-\frac{c}{ax+b})^2=-\frac{cx}{ax+b}$. We will solve this equation." This equation is equivalent to $(ax^2+bx+c)c=0$ so you gained nothing.

Comment: @AnneBauval Actually, it is very helpful to put it in this form. Try putting it in Symbolab and see what you get.

Comment: @AnneBauval Regarding the vector, I changed that. It was just a typo.

Comment: Directly, $ax^2+bx+c=0\iff x=\frac{-c}{ax+b}\Rightarrow (-\frac{c}{ax+b})^2=-\frac{cx}{ax+b}.$ But what is exactly your question?

Comment: @AnneBauval My question is if my derivation of the quadratic formula is correct.

Comment: You hide the main part, so may be may be not. At least,  treat separately the case $ax+b=0.$

Comment: "I'll leave out the steps for solving it, since it is just a matter of rearranging to make $x$ the subject"? To solve that is equivalent to solve the quadratic (but with some extra steps, so it's actually harder), so I'd say that your method doesn't work.

Comment: @jjagmath Once again, my aim is to derive the quadratic formula, not to actually solve the quadratic itself.

Comment: How solving the quadratic is different from deriving the quadratic formula?

Comment: Writing it in the matrix form is weird. $x$ is a variable, putting it in the coefficient matrix just seems.. weird.

Comment: @whoisit It is a standard method taught in college level linear algebra

Comment: @jjagmath You must understand that the quadratic formula is a *tool* used to solve quadratics. I am simply deriving this tool, not actually solving quadratics.